# Dynamicaly manage actions in a Cascades multi-selection handler

Tags: qt, qml, blackberry-10, multi-select, blackberry-cascades

I try to handle a set of actions for multiple items selection on a ListView. The context: a RSS reader. An article can be read/unread, marked/unmarked, published/unpublished. Currently, [my code](https://github.com/Kernald/tt-rss-bb10/blob/cf0e40de94905ca1fa0c45b0c4e593b9ed609944/assets/ArticlesListPage/ArticlesListPage.qml#L18) adds every possible action when the multi-selection is started by the user: mark as read, keep unread, … So mark as read is available even if every selected article is already marked as read.

I'm trying to hide irrelevant actions. There's an example in the [documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__multiselecthandler.html) to switch between multiple selection handlers, with predefined action lists. I would need to create an handler for every possibility, so 8 handlers. That's clearly not the solution.

I tried to call [`MultiSelectionHandler::removeAllActions()`](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__multiselecthandler.html#function-removeallactions) every time my selection changes and [`MultiSelectionHandler::addAction()`](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__multiselecthandler.html#function-addaction-action) to add back needed actions. This is the relevant part of my current code:

```js
ListView {
    dataModel: _articleModel
    id: listView

    multiSelectAction: MultiSelectActionItem {
    }

    multiSelectHandler {
        status: qsTr("None selected")
        actions: []

        attachedObjects: [
            ActionItem {
                id: actionMultiRead
                title: qsTr("Mark as read")
                imageSource: "asset:///images/mark_as_read.png"

                onTriggered: {
                    var selectionList = listView.selectionList();
                    listView.clearSelection();
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectionList.length; ++i)
                        _articleModel.data(selectionList[i]).unread = false;
                }
            },
            ActionItem {
                id: actionMultiUnread
                title: qsTr("Keep unread")
                imageSource: "asset:///images/keep_unread.png"

                onTriggered: {
                    var selectionList = listView.selectionList();
                    listView.clearSelection();
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectionList.length; ++ i)
                        _articleModel.data(selectionList[i]).unread = true;
                }
            },

            ActionItem {
                id: actionMultiPublish
                title: qsTr("Publish")
                imageSource: "asset:///images/publish.png"

                onTriggered: {
                    var selectionList = listView.selectionList();
                    listView.clearSelection();
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectionList.length; ++ i)
                        _articleModel.data(selectionList[i]).published = true;
                }
            },
            ActionItem {
                id: actionMultiUnpublish
                title: qsTr("Unpublish")
                imageSource: "asset:///images/unpublish.png"

                onTriggered: {
                    var selectionList = listView.selectionList();
                    listView.clearSelection();
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectionList.length; ++ i)
                        _articleModel.data(selectionList[i]).published = false;
                }
            },

            ActionItem {
                id: actionMultiStar
                title: qsTr("Star")
                imageSource: "asset:///images/star.png"

                onTriggered: {
                    var selectionList = listView.selectionList();
                    listView.clearSelection();
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectionList.length; ++ i)
                        _articleModel.data(selectionList[i]).marked = true;
                }
            },
            ActionItem {
                id: actionMultiUnstar
                title: qsTr("Unstar")
                imageSource: "asset:///images/unstar.png"

                onTriggered: {
                    var selectionList = listView.selectionList();
                    listView.clearSelection();
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectionList.length; ++ i)
                        _articleModel.data(selectionList[i]).marked = false;
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    onSelectionChanged: {
        if (selectionList().length > 1) {
            multiSelectHandler.status = qsTr("%1 items selected").arg(selectionList().length);
        } else if (selectionList().length == 1) {
            multiSelectHandler.status = qsTr("1 item selected");
        } else {
            multiSelectHandler.status = qsTr("None selected");
        }

        // Update available actions
        multiSelectHandler.removeAllActions();
        for (var i = 0; i < selectionList().length; ++ i) {
            var elt = _articleModel.data(selectionList()[i]);
            if (elt.marked) {
                multiSelectHandler.addAction(actionMultiUnstar);
                console.log("Adding unstar");
            } else {
                multiSelectHandler.addAction(actionMultiStar);
                console.log("Adding star");
            }

            if (elt.published) {
                multiSelectHandler.addAction(actionMultiUnpublish);
                console.log("Adding unpublish");
            } else {
                multiSelectHandler.addAction(actionMultiPublish);
                console.log("Adding publish");
            }

            if (elt.unread) {
                multiSelectHandler.addAction(actionMultiRead);
                console.log("Adding read");
            } else {
                multiSelectHandler.addAction(actionMultiUnread);
                console.log("Adding unread");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While it could greatly be optimized and works fine until the selection changes, it doesn't work anymore after a change: [`MultiSelectionHandler::removeAllActions()`](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__multiselecthandler.html#function-removeallactions) delete the actions, they can't be added back.

Is there any way to achieve this without declaring 8 multi selection handlers?

Answer (score 1):

the question is quite old, and probably you have already solved, but for any other one who stumbled up on this question my solution is to use [MultiSelectionHandler::removeAction()](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__multiselecthandler.html#function-removeaction-action) instead of removeAllActions().

removeAllActions automatically delete the object, thus one should recreated the actions every time.

```
for (var i = 0; i < multiSelectAction.actionCount(); ++ i)
     multiSelectAction.removeAction(multiSelectAction.actionAt(i));
```

Cheers.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't notice the difference. I can't test it right now (I probably still have this code somewhere, I didn't worked on this app in a long time), but I'll keep you posted.

Comment: And I'm sorry, I never took the time to test this, and I don't have the possibility anymore…